# Cannot back up RDS instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

My intention is to export an RDS database and load its data into a local MS-SQL database. I am getting the errors when trying to back-up the RDS instance.

The SQL statement used to initiate the backup is:

```
USE [msdb]
GO
DECLARE   @return_value int
EXEC  @return_value = [dbo].[rds_backup_database]
      @source_db_name = 'abcd',
      @S3_arn_to_backup_to = 'arn:aws:s3:::abcd/test_09_May.bak',
      @KMS_master_key_arn = NULL,
      @overwrite_S3_backup_file = NULL
SELECT    'Return Value' = @return_value
GO
```

The query to check the task status is:

```
exec msdb.dbo.rds_task_status
EXEC msdb.dbo.rds_task_status 
    @db_name = 'abcd', -- sysname
    @task_id = 7 -- int
exec msdb.dbo.rds_task_status @task_id = 7
exec msdb.dbo.rds_task_status @db_name='abcd'
```

The failure reasons from the `taskinfo` column are:

```
1. Aborted the task because of a task failure or an overlap with your preferred backup window for RDS automated backup.
A WebException with status ConnectFailure was thrown.

2. Aborted the task because of a task failure or an overlap with your preferred backup window for RDS automated backup.
Access Denied
```

Comment: You need to make your S3 bucket PUBLIC.

Answer (score 11):

Both the issue are with respect to the S3 bucket:

For the first issue , the s3 bucket you are backing up is not in the same region as your RDS instance

For the second issue, the role that's being used in the Option group doesnt have permissions on the respective bucket. Go to Security Credentials -> Roles -> select the policy and then edit.

Comment: For sure. Check your IAM policy. This is what my problem was. The "prefix" that is asked for in the RDS option group is a folder in your S3 bucket. Make sure your output path includes that prefix folder name OR should just remove that from the IAM resource policy.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use the DB export instead, RDS does not permit to export outside AWS environment.

Answer (score 0):

Adding an S3 policy in my bucket solved the issue for me

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "123",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::mybucket/*"
        }
    ]
}
```